# Ruby on rails Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails

при использование postgresql выдает:

psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

использую mac os 10.8.2,  ruby 1.9.2p290

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, включен ли сервер PostgreSQL

Comment: сервер включен

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что нет подключения к pg.

1. Проверь статус юнита postgresql

`$ sudo systemctl status postgresql.servise`

- имя юнита может отличаться, а также есть маленькая вероятность что в системе используется не systemd

Если напишет что-то вроде disabled, то запусти его:

`$ sudo systemctl enable postgresql.servise`

2. Проверь существует ли кластер

Для начала попробуй подключиться к серверу localhost

```
$ sudo -i -u postgresql 
$ psql -U postgres -h localhost
```

Если выдаст ошибку (вроде - can't open file), тогда необходимо создать кластер

```
$ sudo service postgresql initdb
$ sudo systemctl postgresql.service restart
```

3. Ну а также стоит убедиться что ruby запускает существующую бд и с правильным паролем роли. В основном для роли postgres стандартным паролем является postgres

UPD: не заметил что у тебя мак, но думаю подход схож с linux